# using zipArchive addFile() will not add image to zip

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I've been at this for a while. This actually worked one time, then never again. it simply does not create the zip file. The file does exist.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = "./test" . time() .".zip";

if ($zip->open($filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE) {      
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
}

$thisdir = "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/zip";
$zip->addFile($thisdir . "/trash-icon.png", "/gabage.png");
echo "numfiles: " . $zip->numFiles . "\n";
echo "status:" . $zip->status . "\n";
$zip->close();
```

If I add something like

```
$zip->addFromString("testfilephp.txt", "#1 This is a test string added as testfilephp.txt.\n");
```

it creates the zip with the txt file in it.. but a no go for anytype of existing file.

Comment: `/trash-icon.png` is almost certainly wrong, as it points to the server's root directory. Are you 100% sure the files you are trying to add in fact exist?

Comment: Are you certain that /trash-icon.png actually exists, remembering that it is in the filesystem root directory

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.ziparchive-addfile.php#101605

Comment: hah. I guess it was the file. it's working now. Thanks guys

Answer (score 14):

The ZipArchive::addFile() method accepts the path to the file as its first parameter, but not all paths are created equal. addFile() method silently rejects the file and you never know what went wrong. As can be derived from the question, an alternative approach would be:

```
// $zip->addFile($file);
$content = file_get_contents($file);
$zip->addFromString(pathinfo ( $file, PATHINFO_BASENAME), $content);
```

In addition to getting the code working, file_get_contents() also generates decent error messages.

Comment: Clever workaround! I could find my error this way. I was also saved from going insane!

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Even if the file is_readable add file failed.

Comment: This was the answer that resolved the issue for me.  Thank you.

Comment: Can someone explain to me WHY addfile() is failing silently?

Answer (score 2):

The [**`ZipArchive::addFile()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-addfile.php) method accepts the path to the file as its first parameter.

Here, you are using :

```
$zip->addFile("/trash-icon.png", "/gabage.png");
```

Which means you are trying to add the `/trash-icon.png` file to your archive.

Are you sure this file exists ?

Note **there is a `/` at the beginning of that file's path**, which indicates it's an absolute path.

Maybe that `/` should be removed, to use a relative path ?

Comment: Sorry this was a bad example of one of the many iterations I tried. code is updated

Answer (score 1):

I had similar kind of issue and it was related with the file that I was going to add to the zip archive.

Before adding file to zip archive, it's always better to check if the file exists.

```
$thisdir = "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/zip";
if (file_exists($thisdir . "/trash-icon.png")) {
    $zip->addFile($thisdir . "/trash-icon.png", "/gabage.png");
}
```